# How to get dataframe element not as as a pandas series?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I have the following pandas DataFrame called `df_trainers`:

```
     name                                            trainer
0  BINARY  MLPClassifier(activation='tanh', alpha=0.0001,...
1     REG  MLPRegressor(activation='tanh', alpha=0.0001, ...
2     SVM  SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, ...
```

And I want to get the trainer that corresponds to a specific name.
For example

```
name='SVM'
tr = df_trainers[df_trainers['name'] == name]['trainer']
```

But it says that the type of tr is `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>` instead of `<class 'sklearn.svm.classes.SVC'>`

How to access the trainer itself and not get it as a series ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you get one item `Series`, for scalar select values by `[]` (if [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) return more rows, is possible change `values[1]...` for select second item of `Series`):

```
tr = df_trainers.loc[df_trainers['name'] == name, 'trainer'].values[0]
```

Or:

```
tr = df_trainers.loc[df_trainers['name'] == name, 'trainer'].item()
```

Or:

```
tr = df_trainers.loc[df_trainers['name'] == name, 'trainer'].iloc[0]
```